# Match a url and check whether the url is one among the domain names

Tags: javascript

I have a list of blacklisted URLs in an array

```
var exclusion = ["facebook.com","instagram.com","twitter.com","youtube.com","linkedin.com","google.com","wordpress.org","pinterest.com","plus.google.com","miit.gov.cn","whatsapp.com","apple.com","goo.gl","qq.com","policies.google.com","youtu.be","microsoft.com","maps.google.com","play.google.com","wa.me","accounts.google.com","github.com","en.wikipedia.org","support.google.com"]
```

I will be given a single URL like these to test against the exclusion list

```
https://www.facebook.com
http://www.facebook.com
https://facebook.com
http://facebook.com
http://facebook.com?login=true
http://facebook.com/?login=true
instagram.com
```

Hence

```
for(var i=0;i<exclusion.length;i++)
{
if("https://www.facebook.com".indexOf(exclusion[i]) == 0)
 return true;
}
```

is a highly inefficient technique
since the list has **"domain names"** and the given string are URLs

How do I make a function to return true if the specified URL is in the list of domains.

Comment: Shouldn't `exclusion` be an array and not a string?

Comment: Try the built-in [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) API.

Comment: exclusion is an array of domains with string types. I am given URLs and the function is supposed tor return true or false if the URL belongs to one of the exclusion item.

Comment: I cannot use URL API since this is will also be used for Google Apps Script along with Chrome extension and Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to strip the extraneous parts of the URL off (preferably using the URL API, but if that is not possible, using a regex) and then test whether the result is in the exclusions array:

```js
const exclusion = ["facebook.com","instagram.com","twitter.com","youtube.com","linkedin.com","google.com","wordpress.org","pinterest.com","plus.google.com","miit.gov.cn","whatsapp.com","apple.com","goo.gl","qq.com","policies.google.com","youtu.be","microsoft.com","maps.google.com","play.google.com","wa.me","accounts.google.com","github.com","en.wikipedia.org","support.google.com"]

const tests = ['https://www.facebook.com','http://www.facebook.com','https://facebook.com','http://facebook.com','http://facebook.com?login=true','http://facebook.com/?login=true','instagram.com']

var urlRegex = /^https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?([^/?]+).*$/

const blacklistedURL = (url) => exclusion.includes(url.replace(urlRegex, '$1'))

tests.forEach(url => {
  if (blacklistedURL(url)) {
    console.log(`${url} is blacklisted!`)
  }
})
```

**Note** I've used a trivial URL matching regex in the code for demonstration purposes. There are many sources of better regexes to match URLs, and you should use one of them.

Comment: Thanks So much nick, but I was looking for a function that should return true or false based on the input URL value.

Comment: @CodeGuy see my edit

Answer (score 2):

You can match the URL like below

```
 var exclusion = ["facebook.com","instagram.com","twitter.com","youtube.com","linkedin.com","google.com","wordpress.org","pinterest.com","plus.google.com","miit.gov.cn","whatsapp.com","apple.com","goo.gl","qq.com","policies.google.com","youtu.be","microsoft.com","maps.google.com","play.google.com","wa.me","accounts.google.com","github.com","en.wikipedia.org","support.google.com"]

  var url = "https://www.facebook.com";
  
  for(var i=0;i<exclusion.length;i++)
  {
    if(url.includes(exclusion[i])) {
     console.log('yes');
    }
    else{
    console.log("no");
    }
  }
```

To break the loop when then the URL is matched you can use the `break;` in the `if`

```
var exclusion = ["facebook.com","instagram.com","twitter.com","youtube.com","linkedin.com","google.com","wordpress.org","pinterest.com","plus.google.com","miit.gov.cn","whatsapp.com","apple.com","goo.gl","qq.com","policies.google.com","youtu.be","microsoft.com","maps.google.com","play.google.com","wa.me","accounts.google.com","github.com","en.wikipedia.org","support.google.com"]
    
      var url = "https://www.facebook.com";
      
      for(var i=0;i<exclusion.length;i++)
      {
        if(url.includes(exclusion[i])) {
         console.log('yes');
         break;
        }
        else{
        console.log("no");
        }
      }
```

Comment: This code will match the exclusion string *anywhere* it appears in the `url`, not only when it appears in the actual domain name. For example `https://example.com?url=facebook.com` would be excluded.